# A crumbled, jumbled poem

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay, knowledge, poetry

I wrote a beautiful, verbose poem for you all, but [Riddler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19806/tartar-sauce-gary) went and scrambled the whole thing up! Can you figure out the order of the lines and put it back together again for me? And while you're at it, can you discover what the poem was about?

---

> *Else you'll find them quite well-guarded
>
>   A drinker who is called the same
>
>   An orphan, cinematically
>
>   A pound of text with speech not florid
>
>   Swedish metal takes this name
>
>   When skip was blue, at birth he wore it
>
>   You count on them to win the game
>
>   Written rule, with one before it
>
>   And bywords of reality
>
>   Historic sacred melody
>
>   Dolly sang it, we adored it
>
>   A young pig's tag, an all-time great
>
>   Concrete responsibility
>
>   Some adorned and openhearted
>
>   A certain group has now departed
>
>   History doth these create
>
>   A father of the highest fame
>
>   Together here we rule your fate
>
>   With NASA's help, it all was started
>
>   In others magic worlds await*

---

*A hint that's not really a hint:*

> Focus on figuring out what the lines are referencing first. Once you do that, discovering the true order of the lines should be trivial. Also, since I said it in a comment, I'll repeat it here: Each line *represents something different*. Kind of.

*A hint that's really a hint:*

> There are a couple of lines that should be possibly to figure out without knowing the pattern or the order -- I'd reckon that "A young pig's tag, an all-time great" and "With NASA's help, it all was started" are the two easiest. If you can figure those two out, you should have no problem figuring out the overarching theme and working backwards from there.

Comment: Does the original have a regular rhyme scheme?

Comment: Should I know who/what "skip" is? Or is that sort of thing the reason for the trivia tag?

Comment: @CodeNewbie the regular will rhyme in some fashion or another - when all's said and done, it will read like a regular poem.

Comment: @Alconja that, among a few other things, is a reason for the "Trivia" tag.

Comment: Does the correct answer involve arranging the lines of the poem based on the chronological order of the solutions?

Comment: @GordonK - I was thinking the same thing. From what I can see, I'm guessing we'll have stanzas covering various stages of life. But I can't quite crack enough lines to bring it all together.

Comment: @GordonK the correct order of the lines is not necessarily chronological.

Comment: @Alconja the answer is more concrete than that. Once you figure out what the lines represent, reordering them correctly should be fairly trivial, and you won't have to make any crazy leaps to explain any of them.

Comment: "Dolly sang it, we adored it" - Parton?

Comment: @randal'thor Correct artist, yes. The line specifically represents one of her songs.

Comment: Wow!  Obscure puzzle, but well done!  I wish I had more than one upvote!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each line references

> one of the first twenty books of the Old Testament. So the solution is to sort the lines in the order the books appear in the bible

`With NASA's help, it all was started`

> GENESIS - This is the origin or start and is also the name of a [NASA spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_(spacecraft))

`A certain group has now departed`

> EXODUS - A mass departure of people

`Swedish metal takes this name`

> LEVITICUS - This was a [Swedish Christian metal band](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviticus_(band))

`You count on them to win the game`

> NUMBERS - You count with numbers

`Written rule, with one before it`

> DEUTERONOMY - This is derived from the Greek for 'second law', so there is one rule before it

`Dolly sang it, we adored it`

> JOSHUA - A song by Dolly Parton

`Together here we rule your fate`

> JUDGES - Can rule your fate if you're up in court

`A young pig's tag, an all-time great`

> RUTH - As in Babe Ruth, probably the most famous baseball player of all-time. He shares his name with the pig given the name Babe in the book "The Sheep-Pig" or "Babe, the Gallant Pig" depending on [which side of the Atlantic you reside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheep-Pig)

`A father of the highest fame`

> 1 SAMUEL - Samuel Adams was a Founding Father of the United States

`A drinker who is called the same`

> 2 SAMUEL - Sam(uel) Adams is also the name of a popular American beer

`Some adorned and openhearted`

> 1 KINGS - The kings in a pack of cards can be adorned (of diamonds) or openhearted (of hearts)

`Else you'll find them quite well-guarded`

> 2 KINGS - well guarded in a game of chess

`History doth these create`

> 1 CHRONICLES - Chronicles of history

`In others magic worlds await`

> 2 CHRONICLES - Narnia is the magic land in the Chronicles of Narnia books

`A pound of text with speech not florid`

> EZRA - Ezra Pound was a poet, who favoured short, simple sentences over a more elaborate style

`When skip was blue, at birth he wore it`

> NEHEMIAH - This references [Skip James](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_James), a blues musician, born Nehemiah Curtis James

`An orphan, cinematically`

> ESTHER - The name of the orphan adopted in the film Orphan

`Concrete responsibility`

> JOB - A responsibility

`Historic sacred melody`

> PSALMS - A psalm is a sacred song

`And bywords of reality`

> PROVERBS - Expressions that summarize, or provide a byword for reality

Comment: Though the wording is confusing, you have the right pig, just the wrong name - I'm specifically referencing an "all-time great" with a "young pig's tag" as a qualifier. **tl;dr** use the last name!

Comment: @BaileyM Ah OK thanks, well you've given me a hint to the NASA clue too

Comment: Very, very well done! The only thing you missed was that Kings being "adorned" referenced the king of Diamonds, but everything else is spot on!

Comment: @BaileyM Thanks! I've updated the Kings answer. I thought I'd just put my two cents in with the Babe thing, but after your clarification and I got the theme I felt the urge to get just one or two more. Most enjoyable!

Answer (score 1):

I made it rhyme!*
<sup>****Not really a solution, though.***</sup>

A father of the highest fame
A drinker who is called the same
Swedish metal takes this name
You count on them to win the game

Historic sacred melody
An orphan, cinematically
And bywords of reality
Concrete responsibility

A pound of text with speech not florid
When skip was blue, at birth he wore it
Dolly sang it, we adored it
Written rule, with one before it

A certain group has now departed
With NASA's help, it all was started
Some adorned and openhearted
Else you'll find them quite well-guarded

A young pig's tag, an all-time great
History doth these create
Together here we rule your fate
In others magic worlds await

Comment: I tried this too, but I suspect that's not the correct arrangement.  I think there are five stanzas, each of which contains 2 pairs of 2 rhyming lines.  I haven't figured out how to arrange them yet, though.  I imagine finding what they're referring to will make it more clear.

Comment: I had also considered the possibility of AABB or ABBA. I want to believe they would all follow the same rhyming scheme, too, but I guess anything's possible (like AABB ABBA AABB ABBA AABB, or AABA AABA AABA AABA AAAA).

Comment: Ian, swedish metal should be Nobel Prize? - gold - Written rule with one before it, the golden rule ? do unto others?